# Firebase Storage Image URLs are being console logged onclick but not updated on page with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a React project where i get photo URLs from firebase storage (getPhotoArray function) I have the correct urls being console logged when i click the button, but it doesnt show on my page.

I have multiple photos in the firebase storage folder and i am getting the right amount and right photos console logged in the array(in getPhotoArray function)

```
export const getPhotoArray = async (selectedDonation, setPhotos) => {
  const listRef = ref(storage, '/Images/'+selectedDonation.id);
  const images = []
  listAll(listRef)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.items.length > 0) {
        res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
          // Get the download URL
          getDownloadURL(ref(storage, itemRef.fullPath))
          .then((url) => {
            images.push(url)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
          });
        });
        setPhotos(images)
        console.log(images)
      }else {
        toast.info('No Photos Found, Please Try Again Later')
      }
    }).catch((error) => {

    });   
}
```

```
import React, {useEffect, useMemo, useState} from 'react'
import './donation_information.css'
import {getReceiptURL, getPhotoArray} from '../../API/FirestoreAPI' 

export default function DonationInformation({ selectedDonation, selectedDonationSteps }) {
  const [Photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
 
  const getPhotos = () => {
    getPhotoArray(selectedDonation, setPhotos)
  }

 useEffect(() => {
  setURL('')
  setPhotos([])
 }, [selectedDonation]);

  return (
    <div className='donationInformation'>
        <div className='download-photos'>
          <button onClick={getPhotos}>Show Photos</button>
          {
            useMemo(() => {
              Photos.map((photo) => {
                return <img src="photo" key={photo} alt="" />
              })
            }, [Photos])
          }
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have tried wrapping the Photos.map with useEffect, thats the only thing i could think of

Comment: By the time you call `setPhotos`, `images` are not fully loaded.

Comment: How do i make sure theyre loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with this code:

```
    res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
      // Get the download URL
      getDownloadURL(ref(storage, itemRef.fullPath))
      .then((url) => {
        images.push(url)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      });
    });
    setPhotos(images)
```

Each `forEach` iteration does not wait for `getDownloadURL` to resolve, so your `setPhotos(images)` gets called *before* all URLs are pushed.

In order to wait for the URLs to load, you need to use `async/await`:

```
  listAll(listRef)
    .then(async (res) => {  // <-- remember this `async` keyword. otherwise, using `await` will throw an error
      if (res.items.length > 0) {
        for (const item of res.items) {
          const url = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, itemRef.fullPath))
          images.push(url)
        }
        setPhotos(images)
...
```

On a side note, sending a state setter to the external method doesn't feel like the best approach. You'd better return the image URLs from the method and then set that as your state inside the component.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah last night i figured it out and i passed out right after. Also i will do it without setting the state inside the function.

Comment: Great. If this answer answered your question please accept it so that others can also get help.

Comment: I did. Also i want to upvote it but i cant yet lol.